# htaccess rewrite rules and removing php file extension

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following code in my htaccess file to remove the PHP extensions:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

However, now I added a file in /directory/index.php and I can only access it using /directory/index instead of using just /directory/ (which now throws a 404 not found).

Comment: your RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f checks to see if a file is requested and also exists, so unless a file is requested and exists your rule is never going to match anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep your rules like this in your root .htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# To externally redirect /dir/file.php to /dir/file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(?:index)?(.*?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]

# To internally forward /dir/file to /dir/file.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: What if I not I am doing a pagination and want to use the following structure: domain.com/directory/example has the first page of results while the pagination will be like domain.com/directory/example/page/2 Should I put those rules in a new htaccess under the directory that hosts the example.php file? Thanks!

Comment: Actually this rule has had nothing to do with pagination. It is meant to hide `.php` extension as per your question. Please post a new question with pagination requirements and I will try to answer it accordingly.

Comment: Done, sorry about that :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25030419/htaccess-rewrite-rules-for-pagination-not-working