# htaccess rewrite rules for pagination not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, pagination

I have the following in my htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Multiviews -Indexes 
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# To externally redirect /dir/file.php to /dir/file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(?:index)?(.*?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]

# To internally forward /dir/file to /dir/file.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Now, I am trying to add some pagination rules which left my htaccess file as follows:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Multiviews -Indexes 
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# To externally redirect /dir/file.php to /dir/file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(?:index)?(.*?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]

# To internally forward /dir/file to /dir/file.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteRule ^beta/network/showcase/category/(.*)/page/(.*)$ beta/network/showcase.php?category=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^beta/network/showcase/category/(.*)$ beta/network/showcase.php?category=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^beta/network/showcase/page/(.*)$ beta/network/showcase.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^beta/network/showcase/([0-9]+)$ beta/network/showcase_single.php?id=$1 [L]
```

They all work unless from this one:

```
RewriteRule ^beta/network/showcase/category/(.*)/page/(.*)$ beta/network/showcase.php?category=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

Which throws a 404 error as page not found:

> The requested URL /beta/network/showcase/arts-entertainment/page/2 was not found on this server.

Why is that particular rule failing?

Thanks!

Comment: There is no `/category/` text in the URL you're trying: `/beta/network/showcase/arts-entertainment/page/2`

Comment: Ohhh! I completely overlooked that! It works :)

Comment: Glad to know it worked out, cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was resolved per @anubhava response, I overlooked the '/category/' in the URL.